# exit / abort shell script execution conditionally

Tags: bash, exit

I'm writing a bash script that leverages getopt to process a number of options provided after the script name.

I'm accessing my shell through puTTy.

I invoke the script with . scriptname.sh -o --options (is there a better way to execute a bash script?)

I'd like to be able to abort / halt the script, but whenever I use `exit` it not only exits the script, it also closes the terminal/puTTy window.

...which kinda defeats the purpose because what I'm trying to do is set up some kind of --help text output that displays the text but doesn't execute the rest of the script.

What's the deal with `exit` and what should I use to halt/abort the script without closing any parent console window?

Comment: Yes, there's a better way to execute a script. In fact, using `.` is the same as using the `source` command (`help source` for usage) and is not a good idea if you really wanted to execute the script. Instead `chmod a+x scriptname.sh` and then use `./scriptname.sh` to invoke.

Comment: And do not forget about shebang.

Comment: @maksenov: in fact it will work anyway, but you're right that a bang line is a good idea.

Comment: Nice! @Sorpigal. I'm just picking this stuff up in bits and pieces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `exit` is correct, you're just not executing your script correctly.

Using `.` is the same as using the `source` command (`help source` for usage) and is not a good idea if you really wanted to execute the script.

Instead `chmod a+x scriptname.sh` and then use `./scriptname.sh` to invoke it.

The difference is that `source` treats the script as if it had been typed in by you; it runs in the same `bash` session that you're running interactively. This means that any variables it changes remain changed after it finishes. It also means that if you tell the script to `exit`, it will correctly terminate your current bash session.

Comment: Brilliant. That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the super-quick response! (So fast in fact that I must wait 2 minutes to accept the answer...)